# How to install Hugo?

Tags: go, hugo

I have downloaded and unzipped the `hugo_0.11_linux_amd64.tar.gz` file from the [releases page](https://github.com/spf13/hugo/releases), and I cannot figure out how to run the binary. I took a few stabs at using `go run`, and `sh`, but no luck. Can anyone offer a few more details?

Comment: It would be good if this question covered Windows as well as Linux. I know I can put hugo.exe anywhere but where is the best place if I'm using "Git for Windows"? My second thought is to have a 'command-line' folder in 'My Documents' for all my utilites and put that in the Path. I tried putting it in C:\command-line and adding that to the Path but I can't see it in Git bash.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Extract `hugo_0.11_linux_amd64.tar.gz` to a directory. In that directory you should find three files:

```
hugo_0.11_linux_amd64  LICENSE.md  README.md
```

Make sure either `hugo` is in your path or provide a path to it. For example, rename the `hugo_0.11_linux_amd64` executable file to `hugo`. Move the `hugo` executable file to `/usr/local/bin`.

Run

```
$ hugo help
```

Continue to follow the instructions for [Using Hugo](http://hugo.spf13.com/overview/usage).

References:

[Hugo](http://hugo.spf13.com/)

[Hugo Documentation: Getting Started](http://hugo.spf13.com/overview/introduction)

Comment: Okay, I thought what I downloaded was an installation script that needed to be run, I didn't realize that all I had to do was rename it and move it somewhere. This helps a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The [installation page](http://hugo.spf13.com/overview/installing) does mention:

> Once downloaded it can be run from anywhere. You don’t need to install it into a global location.
>   Ideally you should install it somewhere in your path for easy use. `/usr/local/bin` is the most probable location.

As long as:

- you chose the right release for your architecture (linux, Mac or Windows)
- rename the executable to hugo (or make a symlink to it, named hugo)
- your `$PATH` (or `%PATH%` on Windows) environment variable references the executable `hugo`, you can start using it.

  ```
  hugo new site /path/to/site
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but I figured this could help somebody down the road. I'm on `Windows` (yes I know this was for `Linux`) and was running Hugo outside the created directory where `hugo.exe` lives.

**Note that the** `hugo.exe` **doesn't have to live in** `c:\hugo\bin` **as per the example below**

- Download Hugo (64 or 32-bit) from https://github.com/spf13/hugo/releases
- Create a folder on your `C:\` called `Hugo`.
- Create another folder inside of `C:\Hugo` called `bin`
- Unzip the file downloaded from the HUGO URL into the `bin` folder
- Open `cmd.exe` to add the path to HUGO to the windows PATH environment variables. Type `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Hugo\bin`

To verify that hugo is installed globally, under any directory in command prompt type `where hugo` and it'll tell you where it is (in our case, `c:\hugo\bin\hugo.exe`)

From there you should be able to run your Hugo sites from any repository on your HD.

Answer (score 4):

> Platform : Linux

Following works on Linux

> Download and Unzip

```
curl -L https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases/download/v0.54.0/hugo_0.54.0_Linux-64bit.tar.gz | tar xvz
```

NOTE - `-L` flag is used in `curl` to allow github triggered redirects

> Move to /usr/local/bin

```
mv hugo /usr/local/bin/hugo
```

Once moved to this repo, `hugo` would be accessible without setting path.

Comment: Just what I needed for an alpine container. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### Add Hugo Path from inside Powershell

If you don't want to reboot your system,
you can also add the path directly through powershell using this command:

```
$env:Path += ";C:\hugo\bin"
```

(replace with your own path to the hugo executable)

To check if the new variable works, run

```
hugo version
```

If you have multiple Hugo versions installed, you might need to specify the full path to the specific hugo executable you want to use.

### Add Hugo Path (Windows)

n case you want to add the variable in Windows:

- Right-click "This PC" and select "Properties".
- Click "Advanced system settings" and then "Environment Variables".
- Under "System variables", find "Path" and click "Edit".
- Click "New" and enter the path to your Hugo bin directory. In my
  case: C:\hugo\bin.
- Click "OK" on all open windows to save the changes.
- Reboot